# Get action item location

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'd like to have a tutorial in my app that will pop up windows describing how to interact with the interface/menus.

Is there a way to determine in code which action items are visible and where they are located.  I'd like the pop-up to point to them.

Also is there a simple way to determine if there's an overflow button?  I imagine I may have to check for a hardware menu button instead.

Comment: On API level 14 and above, you can use `ViewConfiguration.hasPermanentMenuKey()` to tell if there is a hardware menu key.

Comment: Yah I was hoping to avoid sloppy API assumptions for devices < 14.  Anyone have any ideas for ActionItem locations?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll be damned, despite MenuItem not inheriting from View, somewhere under the hood it is a view and it's id can be passed to findViewById() just like any other view.

Once you have the view you can use getLocationOnScreen()

Ex:

```
View menuItem = findViewById(R.id.menuItem );
int[] location = new int[2];
menuItem.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

Obviously given the unreliable visibility of action items you'll have to be careful with this.

Here was my menu workaround:

```
boolean hasMenu = false;
if (Utils.hasIceCreamSandwich())
    hasMenu = ViewConfiguration.get(this).hasPermanentMenuKey();
else
    hasMenu = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10;
```